# nodejs multiple worker web api

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, multitasking

I have seen the potential of NodeJS recently and try this for a small task to use .

about the following:
i want to create a web service , which allows you to start and stop multiple client instances (multiple nodejs tasks who should run, until i send a stop request to a instance):

so a http server modul waits for start/stop requests (with params) (maybe with express?) like

[start]
http://taskservice/start?user=abc&pass=123

the service should create a instance of a task like:

```
var task = new MyTask();
task.login(user, pass);

task.on("loginsuccess", function() {
  task.startwork();
};
```

[stop identified by user]
http://taskservice/stop?user=abc

The problem is, I do not know how this can be best implemented . It must always be able to create any number of tasks and the tasks must run until I say stop . (the tasks require very little performance)

Does anyone have an idea or a small code example ?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this is the proper way to do it but I think you can do it with forever. Check this link; http://www.codingdefined.com/2014/08/use-of-forever-in-nodejs.html

You can stop and start child nodejs processes through your root script.